Is it posible to disable replacing "%" to the current file in commands?
I'm using a command to transform an URL to another form in my text_file:
:r! my_command 'https://example.fqdn.com/path%20with%20loads%20of%20spaces'

The problem is that every % char is converted into the name of the current text_file, so i
I end up executing:
:r! my_command 'https://example.fqdn.com/pathfilename20withfilename20loadsfilename20offilename20spaces'

Is there a way to disable this usually very useful behavior in cases like this?

You have to escape the % (\%).
You can use the command-line window to escape these % in one shot.

:r! my_command 'https://example.fqdn.com/path%20with%20loads%20of%20spaces' enter you command
Ctrl f toggle the command line window
:s/%/\\%/g Enter Escape the % in the command
Enter run the modified command

An alternative is to use the execute command:
:exe ':r! my_command' fnameescape("'https://example.fqdn.com/path%20with%20loads%20of%20spaces'")

